# What does this limit verification say?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have to verify the limit
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{2n^2}{n^2+1}=2$$
With $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (actually, it's the limit of an integer sequence).

So I set up the inequality
$$\left| \, \frac{2n^2}{n^2+1} - 2 \, \right|\lt\varepsilon$$
And solving it, I get
$$n^2\gt\frac{2}{\varepsilon} - 1$$
Now what? It isn't acceptable for $\varepsilon \geq 2$, thus what we conclude?

Intuitively I understand that the initial limit is true, but I can't come up with a formal justification.

Comment: In the formal definition of the limit of a sequence, if you have an $N$ which forms for one $\epsilon$, it automatically works for all larger $\epsilon$ as well.

Comment: It should be $n \to \infty$. If it is $x \to +\infty$ then the limit must be $\frac{2n^2}{n^2+1}$.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez yes, I know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show convergence you must show that for any $\varepsilon>0$ there is an $N$ such that the inequality holds for all $n>N$.  For $\varepsilon>2$ the inequality is automatically satisfied.  For smaller $\epsilon$ you can take $n> \sqrt{\frac{2}{\varepsilon} - 1}$.

Comment: For $\varepsilon \geq 2$ doesn't the inequality lose sense? $n$ would be complex

Comment: @mattecapu, I refer back to my comment above. The point is that you don't really have to worry about what happens for $\epsilon \ge 2$, since an $N$ which works for some $\epsilon < 2$ automatically works for any $\epsilon \ge 2$.

Comment: That's a perfectly good point. Thank you! Very helpful

Comment: Please, see what you have written. $\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{2n^2}{n^2+1}$. The fraction does not depend on $x$.